GTK+ load png without loaders.cache
Is it possible to load a PNG image without using of loaders.cache file?
The background is, i dont want to change / recreate the loaders.cache file on every directory change.
A another option for me was to have a loaders.cache with a direct path link like this:
"libpixbufloader-png.dll"
"png" 5 "gdk-pixbuf" "PNG" "LGPL"
"image/png" ""
"png" ""
"\211PNG\r\n\032\n" "" 100

But with this, GTK+ not search in the working directory.
It was using the path C:\MinGW64\libpixbufloader-png.dll
(The working path is C:\MinGW64\bin\proj\gtk\_package\libpixbufloader-png.dll).
I tried to set g_setenv("GDK_PIXBUF_MODULEDIR", module_dir, TRUE); and g_setenv("GDK_PIXBUF_MODULE_FILE", module_dir, TRUE); to the working directory but this dont have any effect.
I use GTK 3.20.

I found a way to solve my question.
I rebuild GdkPixbuf from here with following meson settings:
meson setup _build . -Dman=false
meson compile -C _build

Copying the new libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll to my executable directory, makes it possible to load PNG images without the loaders.cache file.
As background info:
I installed GTK3 from this manual. The default installed libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll (2.42.11.0) was build without enabled loaders.
The libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll I build have version 2.42.13.0 and the loaders are default enabled:


How do you load the image???
Just specify the path and done.
GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new_from_file ("./myfile.png");

Works without any issues.

EDIT:
Here is working sample:
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void destroy (GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data) {
    g_application_quit(G_APPLICATION(data));
}

static void activateWindow(GtkApplication *app) {
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);

    GtkWidget *actionBar = gtk_action_bar_new();

    GtkWidget *quitButton = gtk_button_new();
    GtkWidget *quitLabel = gtk_label_new("Quit");
    gtk_button_set_child(GTK_BUTTON(quitButton), GTK_WIDGET(quitLabel));
    gtk_action_bar_pack_start(GTK_ACTION_BAR(actionBar), GTK_WIDGET(quitButton));
    g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON(quitButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(destroy), app);


    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), box);

    GtkWidget *img = gtk_image_new_from_file("./sample.png");
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand (img, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand (img, TRUE);

    gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (box), actionBar);
    gtk_box_append (GTK_BOX (box), img);

    gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 400, 200);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("my.sample.app", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activateWindow), NULL);
    return g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
}


If my research is correct, you have two reasons why this work.
Your environment path is configured or
In your subfolders the loaders.cache is located.
Your line of code can done without any problems. But if you want to show the image, you must have set up the loaders.
I.e. gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(image0), "C:\\MinGW64\\bin\\proj\\gtk\\glade\\logo.png");

@Erz Sorry, but no. I do not have any specific environment variables and I do not use loader for this sample. Just add an image to current directory or edit source to point to a directory with image file. You will either see an image, or "bad image" icon if relative path is incorrect.

Which gtk version are you using?

I am currently writing for gtk4

Ok, thats the reason why I can not use your code.
I changed some functions to make it compile.
When I run the code, I have following error: Could not load a pixbuf from /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png
